# Form Submit Event's range is null

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a script which runs whenever a form is submitted. I get the range with `event.range` however whenever I try to do anything with it, it returns an error such as

```
TypeError: Cannot find function getA1Notation in object [object Object]. (line 10, file "Code")
```

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Show the code, please.

Comment: There's not much to it. The code that throws the error is `event.range.getA1Notation`, or `event.range.getRow()` etc.

Comment: There is more to it than you think. You need to show the code that leads to this error before anyone can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: How are you testing your code ? Do you try by sending a form?  Or from the script editor?

Comment: Serge: Yeah, I'm submitting a form each time to test.

Comment: Scamp. The only thing before that is `function setReadableTime(e) {`. It's literally one of the first things I try to do, and when it gets to the point described above is when it throws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have put it together correctly you need to change the **e** to **event** or **event** to **e**

> The only thing before that is function setReadableTime(**e**)
>
> The code that throws the error is **event**.range.getA1Notation, or
>   **event**.range.getRow()

Comment: So I think that was just plain ignorance on my part, thanks for the help haha

Comment: this procedure would have been so much simpler had you posted your code.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I can't say what you're doing wrong, but I can tell you that what you're trying is possible. So I'd guess you've got some syntax muddled.

Here is a function that works fine for me. I have it set to trigger as follows:

[image: Triggers]

#### Code

```
function test (e) {
  Logger.log( e.range.getA1Notation() );
  Logger.log( e.range.getRow() );
}
```

#### Results

[image: Logs]

#### References

- Spreadsheet Form Submit Events from [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events).
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I already had that. The real problem was me just being stupid and doing `event` when the object was infact `e` -_-

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that? Oh yeah - you never posted your code! Any of the people who wasted time on this could have answered the question in seconds if you had.